# Linux network monitor showing connections per process

Tags: linux, network-monitor, command-line

I'm looking for a network monitor running on Linux, showing me in real-time

- open connections
- the process owning them
- the target IP (and optionally port)
- allow me to "freeze" the output (i.e. pause updating, so I can investigate details before they disappear)

Preferably for the command-line (strong preference), alternatively with GUI. I don't want a background service I have to visit with a different frontend, also not in the browser.

I'm aware of

- iftop: doesn't show me the application behind a connection
- ifstat: doesn't update real time
- iptraf: again lacks the application part (unless I've missed that), and also forces me to chose between showing the IP and the resolved host name (I'd prefer seeing both together)

[iptraf-ng](https://fedorahosted.org/iptraf-ng/) comes closest to what I'm after, but lacks the details I've pointed out and need.

The software should be open-source and free, as well as preferably being available as a `.deb` in the repositories (Linux Mint 18.1 here; PPAs definitely acceptable).

No need for package capturing etc. Main purpose is to find out which application connects where to and when :)

---

For a work-around, I just figured I can use `iftop`, watching its output, hit <kbd>P</kbd> to freeze it, pick the "suspicious IP address", and then (in another terminal window) run `lsof -i` in a loop – canceling it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as it spit out the details needed:

```
while true; do
   line="$(lsof -i|grep 123.183.209.138)"
   [[ -n "$line" ]] && echo "$line"
   sleep 1;
done
```

But of course this would only work for repeating appearances (or connections staying open long enough).

Comment: what does "sudo netstat -tapn" do for you? I think that will provide most of the info, if not teh actual bandwidth use....

Comment: @ivanivan looking like a "cleaner variant" of my `lsof -i`, but lacking the process owner :)

Comment: Add an "e" to those flags - tapne adds 2 columns, shows the UID (not name, sorry, that may be overriden if you skip the n flag though) and what inode - see http://superuser.com/questions/719649/linux-netstat-how-to-display-the-owner-of-programs-using-ports

Comment: @ivanivan Yes, that gives more details (e.g. the UID). But it's not what I'm looking for. E.g. it's not updating in real-time. Thanks anyway!